# Future in the past . Left/were leaving

Tags: grammar

> I lost my passport the day before we  **were leaving**
> for our honeymoon.

> I lost my passport the day before we **left**
> for our honeymoon.

A grammar exercise suggest that choosing "left" is wrong. Why?

Comment: Both are grammatical and normal. In fact, I'd say that the *left* version is more common—but that doesn't make the *were leaving* version any less legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implied meaning of the first example is that the passport was lost on the day before the holder (and spouse) **was due to leave**, given that the loss of the document might have led to the postponement or cancellation of the honeymoon. But this is more about the protocols of travel than it is about grammar.

The second example makes it clear that the couple proceeded with their honeymoon as planned in spite of the loss of the passport - which is quite possible.

I can't see why either version is wrong, depending on what the speaker means to say.